# Code Coverage in .Net Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, code-coverage, dotcover

How can I generate code coverage in .Net Core 2.0?

I tried the following:

```
"TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe" --collect:"Code Coverage"
```

But I got this error message:

```
Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: Cannot find CodeCoverage.exe.
```

I tried dotCover latest version 2017.2 which I am able to get the coverage on the local machine, but when the same is run in the TFS Build no coverage information is generated.

I am not sure when NetCore Test task in TFS will get support for code coverage.

How can I publish the results from DotCover in TFS also, to use DotCover Commandline to generate the Coverage for .Net Core?

Comment: @slartidan This is related to SonarQube as well because the current MS Build Task in TFS is a not able to analyze the Net Core. I am using SonarCLI for the analysis

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**VSTest** task cannot run .NET core tests as it uses the Test platform version 1. To run .NET core tests, we recommend using the **.NET core task(preview)** with the test command.

However, Code coverage and other data collection is **not supported** yet,  no agent support.

> We are fixing this issue as part of this
>   https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/pull/1149/files Will update
>   the thread once fix is gone and new agent is released. thread
>   https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/issues/579#issuecomment-324401462
>
> Source Link: [**VSTest task fails to execute tests in .NET Core 2.0 test project**](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/5066)

Comment: I'm aware of the work from the vsts, I wanted to know how to publish the coverage as DotCover uses the TestWindow/vstestconsole.exe where as NetCore doesn't use same.

Comment: Code coverage now seems to work when using  --collect "code coverage"  as command line arguments for the VSTS "dotnet" (option "test") task. It warns that it only works for windows environments though.

Comment: Would you be able to follow this up Patrick (pretty please)? I just tried the command `dotnet test c:\sln\test.csproj  --collect "code coverage"` and it works. I'm on VS2017 15.9.11, could we please get the Test > Windows > Code Coverage menu enabled? Seems like that's the last piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 7):

[Coverlet](https://github.com/tonerdo/coverlet) is a cross platform code coverage available as NuGet package.

Just add it on your **test** project:

```
dotnet add package coverlet.msbuild
```

And run it altogether with `dotnet test` command as parameter:

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true
```

Supported Formats:

- json (default)
- lcov
- opencover
- cobertura

I made more detailed implementation about it here: [.Net Core Unit Test and Code Coverage with Visual Studio Code](https://dev.to/deinsoftware/net-core-unit-test-and-code-coverage-with-visual-studio-code-37bp)

Answer (score 0):

It had been a long time since this question was asked, but I think my answer below will be helpful to execute tests for the projects on .NET Core 2 and to generate coverage report using DotCover tool.

1. Download and install Jetbrains dotcover console setup
2. On the command line execute the command as below, which will identify the test projects in the solution and generate coverage report in HTML format. You can also generate in different formats as JSON, NDependXML or DetailedXML.

> dotcover analyse /TargetExecutable:"C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" /TargetArguments:"test
>   **Path_To_Your_Solution_File**"
>   /Output:report.html /ReportType:HTML

You can also run and generate test coverage over .csproj file.

Comment: I am using dotcover exactly the same as your example. The output window states that it has executed the tests and that the test run was successful, but then it just hangs and doesn't produce any code coverage results. I am using the latest version of dotcover (2017.3.5). Any ideas?

Comment: You should use the 2018 version of dotcover. I have faced the same issue upgrading the version fixed the issue specifically for .net core.